# C++ Structure: ENTITY entity=ENTITY::CURRENT, What it means?

Tags: c++, structure

I'm starting to work in a new company and i've to work in C++ on a old project.
So, i've forgot some c++ itself structure of code.
In a function, i've the double colon :: in a function and i d'ont know how to understand that here.

I know for exemple if i've got the ENTITY::SRP, that made "link" the the SRP class in ENTITY Namespace, butHere i d'ont found the class CURRENT.

Here's the example:

```cpp
void FlushBuffer (ENTITY entity=ENTITY::CURRENT,int msg_type=IN_MSG::T_CONT);
```

So, CURRENT is it a specific word in C++?

Thanks in advance.

```
class ENTITY
{
    protected:
    char entity[16];

    public:
    #ifdef _BIG_ENDIAN    
    enum IMM {
        ALL=0,
        SSP=0x53535000,
        SRP=0x53525000,
        AUX1=0x41555831,
        AUX2=0x41555832,
        ANY=0x414E5900,
        CURRENT=-1};
```

I found this, so if i want to acces my enum, I just have to do ENTITY::AUX2 for example? and the enum nam IMM it's not needed?

Comment: Have you looked at where `ENTITY` is defined? `CURRENT` must be in there somewhere (or hidden behind a macro). Use the search function in whatever editor you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ENTITY` might be an `enum` type with `CURRENT` and `SRP` as its members (enumerators).

Note that you don't need to use fully qualified enumerator name (the one which starts with `ENTITY::`) when using enumerators. Microsoft compiler issues a [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173704%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in that case. `ENTITY` is not a namespace, it is the name of a new type.